# createNativeQuery - return Page

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following custom implementation of my repository.

```
public final EntityManager entityManager;

public ImputacionRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Override
public List<ImputacionData> imputacionesList() {
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT " + "empleado.id as empleadoId,"
            + "MAX(imputacion.dia) as dia," + "imputacion.id as id " + "FROM rrhh.empleado empleado "
            + "JOIN rrhh.imputacion imputacion ON imputacion.empleado = empleado.id "
            + "WHERE empleado.id NOT IN (SELECT empleado.id " + "FROM rrhh.empleado empleado "
            + "LEFT JOIN rrhh.imputacion imputacion ON imputacion.empleado = empleado.id " + "WHERE "
            + "(imputacion.dia >= '2017-06-01' AND imputacion.dia <= '2017-10-31') "
            + "GROUP BY empleado.id,imputacion.empleado, imputacion.id) " + "AND true=true "
            + "GROUP BY empleado.id,imputacion.empleado, imputacion.id ORDER BY imputacion.dia DESC");
    List<ImputacionData> imputaciones = q.getResultList();
    return imputaciones;
}
```

And I need that instead of returning a `List<ImputacionData>`, return **`Page<ImputacionData>`**, but I do not know if it is possible, and how to do it.

Comment: You want return `Page<ImputacionData>`? What do you mean 'Page'?

Comment: Right, I need that exactly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you can use [page implementation in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html), in Your case it's may look like:

```
    @Override
    public Page<ImputacionData> imputacionesList() {
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT " + "empleado.id as empleadoId,"
            + "MAX(imputacion.dia) as dia," + "imputacion.id as id " + "FROM rrhh.empleado empleado "
            + "JOIN rrhh.imputacion imputacion ON imputacion.empleado = empleado.id "
            + "WHERE empleado.id NOT IN (SELECT empleado.id " + "FROM rrhh.empleado empleado "
            + "LEFT JOIN rrhh.imputacion imputacion ON imputacion.empleado = empleado.id " + "WHERE "
            + "(imputacion.dia >= '2017-06-01' AND imputacion.dia <= '2017-10-31') "
            + "GROUP BY empleado.id,imputacion.empleado, imputacion.id) " + "AND true=true "
            + "GROUP BY empleado.id,imputacion.empleado, imputacion.id ORDER BY imputacion.dia DESC");
    Page<ImputacionData> page = new PageImpl<>(q.getResultList());
    return page;
}
```

Comment: that's correct, I'm missing one thing, in my method comes the page to apply it to the query from my front. (public Page <ImputacionData> imputacionesList (Pageable pageable)), as I apply it to the query. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you answer me the last thing I asked? Thank you very much.

Comment: It works yes, but linh in response header for pagination are false... a solution?